# Как можно максимально быстро считывать и записывать данные в текстовый файл

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных, файлы

Я делаю примерно так:

`StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(beginFile);
string str = sr.ReadLine();
...
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(endFile);
sw.WriteLine();`

Есть ли какие-нибудь более быстрые способы это делать? Кроме чтения всего файла до конца и полной записи. Все это не помогает, работает очень долго.

Comment: А для какой цели нужно читать этот файл? Можно выделить в памяти достаточно большой буфер и считывать данные как у бинарника. Далее буфер разбивать по строкам, если это вообще необходимо.

Не пытаетесь ли Вы сделать какое-то копирование файлов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый быстрый метод записи — писать файл не как текстовый, а как бинарный. Вам придётся подготовить набор байт вручную. Имея набор байт, вы можете воспользоваться [отображаемым в память файлом](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

Только зачем вам это? Неужели это — реальная проблема в вашей программе?